# Is an Activity in paused state after onStart() or onPause() returns?

Tags: android, activity-lifecycle

According to the document by android [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity), an activity has essentially four states, and one of them is called *paused* and it is the state of an activity which has lost focus but is still visible. My question is this: 
Is this state limited only to that situation or we can generalize it to this new definition: An activity state is *paused* right after *onStart()* or *onPaused()* returns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this state limited only to that situation or we can generalize it
>   to this new definition: An activity state is paused right after
>   onStart() or onPaused() returns.

No. Its not limited to that situation.

**If you read further it says:**

> **The foreground lifetime of an activity happens between a call to
>   onResume() until a corresponding call to onPause()**. During this time
>   the activity is in front of all other activities and interacting with
>   the user. **An activity can frequently go between the resumed and paused
>   states -- for example when the device goes to sleep, when an activity
>   result is delivered, when a new intent is delivered** -- so the code in
>   these methods should be fairly lightweight.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but let me say another example. Imagine an Activity is created and immediately onStart() is called and after that immediately onResume() is called and now is running. Has this activity ever been in a paused state until now?

Comment: @user1302157 No. if you see the life-cycle diagram, it depicts that in this straigtht forward flow activity won't be in paused state. You can also check the table below which shows the lifecycle movement.